# Is redrawing the contents of a DIV by means of a function call possible?

Tags: javascript, html

Just an amateur/hobbyist here - what this is supposed to do is be a tool for a board game I play with friends.  The plastic sliders the game uses are too loose to be reliable so I wanted to reproduce that functionality as a webpage to use on a smartphone while playing.

It gets a character's name from a form (on another page) and supplies it to
the one below.  Based on the name, it chooses the right set of attributes from the switch statement (I removed all but two cases for the sake of simplicity), runs through a for loop to display the attributes in a list and highlight the "current" value as green.  Two buttons are supposed to increase or decrease the array counter ("speed"), and rerun the function that draws the array with the new highlighted value. innerHTML is meant to redraw the div ("speeddiv") with the new results.

Now the javascript console in chrome is telling me that speedcounter() and character are undefined.  I suspect this has something to do with the scope of the function and variables I'm using being lost through innerhtml.  All I want to do is find a way to easily redraw/replace the stat counter so it appears that the highlighted number is moving up and down as you press the + or - buttons, within the div.
I'm only working on the "speed" attribute below, so I can get that working first.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; }
#dossier {height: 10%; text-align: center; background: #808080}
#container {height: 90%; width: 100%; background: #000000; overflow: hidden; float: left}
#stats {height: 100%; width: 100%; float: left; position: relative}
#speeddiv, #mightdiv, #sanitydiv, #knowledgediv {width: 25%; height: 100%; text-align: center; float: left; position: relative; overflow: hidden}
#speeddiv {background: #0000FF}
#mightdiv {background: #FF0000}
#sanitydiv {background: #FFFF00}
#knowledgediv {background: #00FF00}
</style>

<?php $character = $_GET["character"]; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

 var character = "<?php echo $character ?>";
 var sp;
 var speed;

 function speedcounter() {
  var spx;
  document.write('   <h2>Speed</h2></br>');
  document.write('<input type="button" onclick="addspeed();" value="+"><br />');   

  for (spx=8; spx>=0; spx--) {
   if (spx == speed) { 
   document.write('<font color=#00FF00>');
   }
   document.write(sp[spx]); 
   document.write('<font color=#000000><br />');
  }
  document.write ('<input type="button" onclick="remspeed();" value="-">'); 
 }

function addspeed() {
 if (speed < 8) {
  speed++;
  document.getElementById("speeddiv").innerHTML = "<script type="text/javascript">speedcounter();<\/script>";
 }
}

function remspeed() {
 if (speed > 0) {
  speed--;
  document.getElementById("speeddiv").innerHTML = "<script type="text/javascript">speedcounter();<\/script>";
 }
}

switch (character) {
 case "brandon":

 sp=["0","3","4","4","4","5","6","7","8"];
 mt=["0","2","3","3","4","5","6","6","7"];
 sn=["0","3","3","3","4","5","6","7","8"];
 kn=["0","1","3","3","5","5","6","6","7"];

 speed=3;
 might=4;
 sanity=4;
 knowledge=3;

 break;

 case "flash":

 sp=["0","4","4","4","5","6","7","7","8"];
 mt=["0","2","3","3","4","5","6","6","7"];
 sn=["0","1","2","3","4","5","5","5","7"];
 kn=["0","2","3","3","4","5","5","5","7"];

 speed=5;
 might=3;
 sanity=3;
 knowledge=3;

 break;
 }

</script>

<div id="dossier">
 <script type="text/javascript">
  document.write(character);
 </script>
</div>
<div id="container">
 <div id="stats">
  <div id="speeddiv">
   <script type="text/javascript">
    speedcounter();
   </script>
  </div>
  <div id="mightdiv">
   <h2>Might</h2></br></br>
  </div>
  <div id="sanitydiv">
   <h2>Sanity</h2></br></br>
  </div>
  <div id="knowledgediv">
   <h2>Knowledge</h2></br></br>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a jsfiddle from the code you've posted http://jsfiddle.net/amelvin/bwwce/ - working on it interactively in there may help.

I think your problem is what is happening with the document.write; [the section on document.write](http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html) explains that what document.write does is not very predictable.

Use a javascript library like jquery to insert elements into the webpage rather than document.write - [the html() method in jquery](http://api.jquery.com/html/) (amongst others) allows you dynamically and predictably manipulate any aspect of the page based on events like button pushes, adding or removing buttons or divs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  I didn't know about jsfiddle so I'm definitely going to use that from now on.  I'll also look into jquery too but I was trying to keep the setup as vanilla as possible.  Thanks again!

Comment: I am a firm follower of staying as vanilla as possible but with jQuery routines baked into the javascript renderer's of today's browsers you can pretty much rest assured that your code is still respectable and highly deployable with that library intact. It would be very wise to get familiar with jQuery. Even for a hobbyist!